# Dictionary of lists won't save as DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Background:**
I have a dictionary of lists, with with the following structure:
**(note: there are more keys than shown here)**:

```
urls = {

'Course': ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/appetizer/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/breakfast/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/brunch/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/dessert/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/dinner/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/drink/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/lunch/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/salad/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/sandwich/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/side_dish/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/snack/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/soup/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/soup_and_stew/',
                'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/course/stew/'],
     'Cuisine': ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/african/',
                 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/basque/',
                 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/belgian/',
                 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/brazilian/',
                 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/british/']
}
```

**What I'm trying to do:**
 Using BeautifulSoup, I intend to iterate through these links and scrape certain information from a recipe websites. I would like to store this information in a pandas DataFrame, for ease of iterating through, with a loop.

**My Code (that doesn't work):**
I have written this code, that I was expecting to create a DataFrame -

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(urls,orient='index').transpose()
```

**Code Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-46950d5ba288> in <module>
----> 1 df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result,orient='index').transpose()

~/anaconda3/envs/DataScience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
   1233         orient = orient.lower()
   1234         if orient == "index":
-> 1235             if len(data) > 0:
   1236                 # TODO speed up Series case
   1237                 if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):

TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

**Code for creating the structure**
This is the code, that creates the structure:

```
from recipe_scrapers import scrape_me
import re

scraper = scrape_me('https://www.simplyrecipes.com/index/')
raw_dict = scraper.links()
result = []
for d in raw_dict:
    for key, value in d.items():
        # If the key is not equal to 'href' and the value doesn't contain ''/recipe' then that pair is skipped.
        if key != "href" or "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/" not in value:
            continue
        txt = ''
        for i in re.findall("recipes/.*", value):
            txt += i
            title = txt.split('/')[1]


            result.append({title: value})
```

Note:`recipe_scraper` (specifically `scraper.links()`)  dependency allows you to return a list of dictionaries containing all of the `<a>` tag attributes. The attribute names are the dictionary keys.

**Help:**
I would be very grateful if someone could tell me why my code isn't work (I'm relatively new!) and what recommendations you might have for the correct / most elegant way to store this information for iterating through, using a loop.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(urls).stack()`?

Comment: what does "not work" mean, **exactly**?

Comment: "what recommendations you might have for the correct / most elegant way to store this information for iterating through, using a loop" not a data frame.  But it really depends on what you mean, *exactly*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I have updated the thread with the code error. By elegant, I really am looking for suggestions on the best way to store the provided structure in a DataFrame

Comment: Your example data would not produce that error. I think you are passing a `Response` object to the data frame constructor, not the dictionary you claim. You **really must** provide a [mcve] for questions seeking debugging help. Otherwise it just devolves into people guessing. Also, you said you wanted to store the information for iterating with a for-loop, which is really not what you want a dataframe for. Again, it is helpful if you told us what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Also, it is really not clear what you expect from the resulting dataframe.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - you've made it clear that you do not wish to help (no problem at all), but I don't know what more information I can provide, other than the code for producing my structure, which I have now included.

Comment: @William no, you are simply refusing to put forward the modicum of effort required to produce a [mcve]. You will find that people are more than willing to help if you do. You should familiarize yourself with the [help] and [ask]. Note, your code is incomplete. We should be able to copy-and-paste your code to reproduce your error. Again, Without that, all we can say is that the object you are passing to the data frame constructor is a `Response` object, which it shouldn't be. That's what the error is telling you. It is not a dict as you claim, or else you wouldn't get that error message.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d9fff2792bf16178d4e450fe7384244e50635733/pandas/core/frame.py#L1229-L1308) is a link to the source code for the `from_dict` constructor, as you can see, nothing is done to the input `data` before trying to call `len(data)` on it, it is the exact same object you pass in. If you do `len(result)` it will throw the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to save my structure into a dataframe successfully using:
 `db = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(urls, orient='index')`